# Iam using magento porto theme and issue is i cant be able to change price by clicking configurable products

Tags: product, price, theme

This is my working place and problem in Price change price is not changing in main changing in sticky option.

i couldn't find any solution, please help me..

http://vinyl.solutions/index.php/4-x-4/4-x-4-camo-greyscale-decal.html

Comment: what you mean by  "in main changing in sticky option."

Comment: What have you tried? Do you set price differences for your attribute at the config product?

Comment: I mean changing in sticky price but not changing in default page price.

Comment: yes i have already set and it is working on sticky option but not in mail block page.

Comment: try to disable or remove price which you are showing with add to cart header bar (sticky option). And see after that is it working on product page or not

Comment: Perfect now it is working on product page but i also need sticky bar for product option ! Any idea to solve without removing the sticky.

Comment: great. Added my suggestion in answer box. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use clone price for that. Use below block and try to call this in second place.

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.clone_prices" as="prices" template="catalog/product/view/price_clone.phtml" />
```

Or you can call it this way

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, false, '_clone') ?>
```

Comment: i have added this block in catalog.xml file then cloned the price to price_clone.phtml. Now how can i call this price in view.phtml

Comment: price_clone.phtml default coming in magento in view folder. You don't need to create it. you can call it other way also. I have edited it in my answer.

Comment: Great thank you !